# Jboss EAP 7.2 - How to use the SSL keystore and password in Java application since there is no system variables supported for these two variables?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, apache-httpclient-4.x, jboss-eap-7

We are migrating Jboss EAP 6.4 to Jboss EAP 7.2. Jboss 6.4 has system variables supported for keystore and password. Question here is how to use the SSL keystore/password from Jboss EAP 7.2 configuration file (standalone.xml) in Java application since there is no system variables supported for these two variables? Instead of these two variables, Jboss 7.2 uses Elytron framework for TLS.
I'm getting below error since I'm not able to pass these two system variables.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure.

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Jboss 7.2 Standalone.xml file:

```
 <tls>
        <key-stores>
            <key-store name="default-trust-store">
                <credential-reference store="keystore" alias="truststore_pw"/>
                <implementation type="JKS"/>
                <file path="../certs/truststore.jks"/>
            </key-store>
            <key-store name="httpsKS" alias-filter="">
                <credential-reference store="keystore" alias="keystore_pw"/>
                <implementation type="JKS"/>
                <file path="/.../keystore.jks"/>
            </key-store>
        </key-stores>
        <trust-managers>
            <trust-manager name="default-trust-manager" key-store="default-trust-store"/>
        </trust-managers>
        <server-ssl-contexts>
            <server-ssl-context name="httpsSSC" cipher-suite-filter="[ciphers here]" protocols="TLSv1.2" key-manager="httpsKM"/>
        </server-ssl-contexts>
    </tls>
```